How do I add annotations to autodesk forge viewer objects?
I want to add annotations to parts of my model, but I don't understand how to do it. To make you understand my idea, I will attach a photo as I see it. So that when I click on an object, menus appear that I can edit
Could you help me, where could I read about the implementation of this?

Searching for the information "add annotations to objects" I found nothing

There are many ways to add annotations to your models in Viewer.
It seems you're interested in adding a panel with some data connected to some elements from your design. For that, you can follow the Dashboards tutorial as it covers the basics of how to create custom panels and Viewer extensions.
We also have this blog sharing a way to connect with external dbs in Viewer. It adds those properties in the property panel (that shows properties from selected elements) using an input element that lets you edit the values.
